# How to execute console Java application for Task Scheduler?

Tags: java, windows, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

I have a .java console application with no GUI. What script or commands would I need to compile and run it with arguments from the command prompt? I want to have the script run nightly from Task Scheduler, but I've been relying on Eclipse to run my Java code so far.

Answer (score 1):

To compile a java application, use the [`javac` command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html). To actually run the program, use the [`java` command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) (after running the `javac` command).

For example (assuming you have a file named `Driver.java`):

```
javac Driver.java
```

(creates `Driver.class` file)

```
java Driver arg0 arg1 arg2
```

(runs the `Driver` program with `arg0` `arg1` and `arg2` as command line arguments)

Comment: Do I have to compile it every time? Or can I just call the "java" command on Driver.class after the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a runnable jar file with Eclipse. Select `File -> Export` from the menu and then start the `Runnable Jar File` wizzard. You can select the launch configuration that you usually use to start your application. Then you also select the location and name of the jar file, where your application is exported.

To run the application from the console, you just use the command

```
java -jar exported-jar-file.jar
```